# how can i delete an acl rule from a registry key using the command line

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, cmd

I would like to know how to delete a "Deny rule" that makes imposible to modify a register key, using the command line.

Context:

In windows every file extension association resides in:

```
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\
```

For instance the default app for **.mp4** files is managed in:

```
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.mp4\UserChoice
```

The **Userchoice** key has a deny permission above all other permisions. The following picture shows what I mean:
[image]

I have tried with Powershell using `set-acl` but due the same deny Deny rule I can't modify anything of that key.

Why all this? I was creating a script to define easily through command line the default app for an specific extension. The change in the registry is a must to make this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried non-Microsoft solutions? Give http://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/command-line-version-setacl-exe/ a go.

Comment: excelent tool, i ask for help to the creator via tweeter and he tells me how to do it..the command finally was : setacl.exe -on HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.mp4\UserChoice -ot reg -actn trustee -trst n1:voodoomsrlaptop\voodoomsr;ta:remtrst;w:dacl ... that effectively delete the first deny rule, and left alone the second full control rule, with the result that i now can modify the content without any trouble, more info in http://helgeklein.com/setacl/faq/#revoking-permissions-may-not-revoke-all-aces-of-a-trustee-on-a-given-object

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the script with elevated permissions  (i.e. did you start Powershell with "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: yes, is the deny rule the problem, check by yourself, every UserChoice has this deny rule